# API Call to Document Library, how to get a subfolder's name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I have been trying to make a call to a specific subfolder. Oddly if I call directly to:

```
'sites/website/RootFolder/Folders(\'subfoldername\')/Files
```

It returns the subfolder items but it won't give me additional columns like Category or Author.

I can get all the data by doing a regularly api call but it gives me all folders.  I need to filter it to one folder but I am not sure what column type to select for this?

The call I am doing but don't see the "folder" names?

```
    var sel='FileLeafRef,File_x0020_Type,Category,Category0,OData__Author,Folder,File,ContentType';
    var url=pth+'/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle(\'Library\')/items?$select='+sel;
```

Comment: Have you tried _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/FolderA/Subfolder1')/Properties

Comment: also you can get folder name using this /_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Library')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title

Answer (score 1):

You could add filter in the end of rest api like this:

```
&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'FolderName'
```

For example:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File_x0020_Type,Category,Category0,OData__Author,Folder,File,ContentType&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'Folder1'
```